# Why do we sometimes omit and sometimes retain the conjunctions "because/while/when etc" when reducing adverb clauses?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, phrase-usage

We can reduce this sentence

"**Because she has a test next week, she is studying very hard.**" (1-1) -> "**Having a test next week, she is studying very hard.**" (1-2)

"**Before he bought the house, he did a lot of research.**" (2-1)-> "**Before buying the house, he did a lot of research.**" (2-2)

"**After she had lunch, she went back to work.**" (3-1)-> "**After having lunch, she went back to work.**" (3-2)

"**While I was walking home from work, I saw an old friend**" (4-1) -> "**While walking home from work, I saw an old friend**" (4-2)

"**As I was walking home from work, I saw an old friend**" (5-1) -> "**Walking home from work, I saw an old friend**" (5-2)

We know that a gerund plays a role of a noun and a present participle plays a role of an adjective. But a noun or an adjective can play a role of an adverb.

Is "**Having a test next week**" in (1-2) a gerund or a present participle?

Is "**before**" in (2-2) a preposition and "**buying the house**" is a gerund?

Is "**after**" in (3-2) a preposition and "**having lunch**" is a gerund?

Is "**while**" in (4-2) a preposition and "**walking home from work**" is a gerund?

Is "**Walking home from work**" in (5-2) a gerund or a present participle?

**Why do we sometimes omit and sometimes retain the conjunctions "because/while/when etc" when reducing adverb clauses?**

Comment: It is probably  a question of brevity without changing the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: It strikes me that, in your examples, you include the conjunction/preposition when it indicates past or future. In 4-2, *you could say* "Walking home...." Hm, can I think of a present-tense example in which we're forced to retain it?...